# cx_Freeze "ImportError: cannot import name 'vision"

Tags: python-3.x, cx-freeze

I am using TensorFlow in a Python script that I am trying to freeze. Everything builds fine, but when I try to run it, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\.conda\envs\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts__startup__.py", line 14, in run module.run()
File "C:\Users\.conda\envs\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 26, in run exec(code, m.dict)
File "config.py", line 21, in
File "E:\Projects\test.py", line 7, in from google.cloud import vision
ImportError: cannot import name 'vision'
```

I am using cx_Freeze. The google library has been successfully added in the `Setup.py` script. The `__init__.py` is also present in the google directory.

`Setup.py`:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import sys
import os

base = None
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = "C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\tcl\\tcl8.6"
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = "C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\tcl\\tk8.6"
os.environ["REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE"] = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "cacert.pem")

if sys.platform == 'win32':
    # base = "Win32GUI"
    base = 'Console'

if sys.platform == 'win64':
    # base = "Win64GUI"
    base = 'Console'

include = ['numpy.core._methods', 'numpy.lib.format', 'jinja2', 'jinja2.ext', 'asyncio', 'constants', 'jinja2.debug']

packages = ['asyncio', 'jinja2', 'jinja2.ext', 'flask', 'numpy', 'pandas', 'connect_db', 'pymysql', 'pymysql.cursors',
            'multiprocessing', 'multiprocessing.pool','google']
excludes = []

options = {'build_exe': {'packages': packages, 'includes': include, 'include_files': includefiles, 'excludes': excludes}}

flaskapp = Executable(script="config.py",
                      targetName="test.exe",
                      icon='test.ico'
                      )

setup(
    name="",
    version="1.0",
    author="Test",
    description="Test",
    options={
        'build_exe': {
            'include_files': includefiles,
            'includes': include,
            'packages': packages,
            'excludes': excludes,
            'build_exe': "build"
        }
    },
    executables=[flaskapp]
)
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @jpeg I finally found the solution.

1. I added `__init__.py` in `/site-packages/google` also in `/site-packages/google/cloud`
2. For Error:`DistributionNotFound: The 'google-api-core' distribution was not found and is required by the application` 
   edited the `/site-packages/google/api_core/__init__.py`

```
import requests_toolbelt.adapters.appengine
requests_toolbelt.adapters.appengine.monkeypatch()
import pkg_resources
old_get_distribution = pkg_resources.get_distribution
from pkg_resources import parse_version

def mp_get_distribution(*args, **kwargs):
    # print args
    # print kwargs
    try:
        res = old_get_distribution(*args, **kwargs)
    except:
        class Mock(object):
            pass

        mock = Mock()
        mock.parsed_version = parse_version("2.6.1") #add sensible value
        mock.version = parse_version("2.6.1") #add sensible value
        return mock

    return res

pkg_resources.get_distribution = mp_get_distribution

from google import api_core
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the GitHub repository, [`google/cloud/__init__.py`](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/blob/master/vision/google/cloud/__init__.py) contains the following code:

```py
try:
    import pkg_resources

    pkg_resources.declare_namespace(__name__)
except ImportError:
    import pkgutil

    __path__ = pkgutil.extend_path(__path__, __name__)
```

Maybe this dynamical import is not recognized by cx_Freeze. Try to add `'pkg_resources'` or `'pkgutil'` to the `'packages'` list in your setup script.

EDIT:

Apparently the `__init__.py` file is also missing from `path_to_python_lib/site-packages/google/cloud/` directory as well when `google-cloud-vision` is installed with pip. Try to manually add an empty `__init__.py` file to this directory as well before freezing.

Comment: @A14 If this still does not work, please run your frozen application from a `cmd` prompt or terminal and add the error message with full traceback (as text) to your question.

Comment: I tried your ans, still same error, I added error in the question

Comment: @A14 I've found a further potential issue and edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: In which folder should I add, as folders are ```/site-packages/google/vision_v1``` etc

Comment: @A14 In my installation the folders are `site-packages/google/cloud/vision_v1` and so on, and the `__init__.py` file is missing from `site-packages/google/cloud/` (sorry, I made a mistake in my answer, corrected now).

Comment: I added ```__init__.py``` file, still getting same error. Also added same file after freezeing, no progress. I see in ```site-packages/google/cloud/``` there's ```vision.py``` file & it is missing after freezing. If I added that file I get ```pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'google-api-core' distribution was not found and is required by the application```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195567/discussion-between-a14-and-jpeg).

Answer (score 0):

I had to modified the solution proposed by A14 as following.

1. add **init**.py in /site-packages/google also in /site-packages/google/cloud  (same)
2. in **init**.py in /site-packages/pkg_ressources add this line after import

   ```
   from pkg_resources import py2_warn
   ```
3. For Error:DistributionNotFound: The 'google-api-core' distribution was not found and is required by the application edited the /site-packages/google/api_core/**init**.py

   ```
    import pkg_resources
    old_get_distribution = pkg_resources.get_distribution
    from pkg_resources import parse_version

    def mp_get_distribution(*args, **kwargs):
        # print args
        # print kwargs
        try:
            res = old_get_distribution(*args, **kwargs)
        except:
            class Mock(object):
               pass

             mock = Mock()
             mock.parsed_version = parse_version("1.16.0") #add sensible value
             mock.version = parse_version("1.16.0") #add sensible value
             return mock

        return res

   pkg_resources.get_distribution = mp_get_distribution

   from google import api_core
   ```